# Tl WN722n v3 installation problem

Tags: networking, software-installation, kali-linux, virtualbox, monitoring

When I use the `make all` or `make` command this error appears. I need help..!

[image: this Is the error]

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this error because of some recent changes in the Linux kernel `netdevice` API. More specifically this `ndo_select_queue` was defined like [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.1/source/include/linux/netdevice.h#L988) in 5.1:

```
u16 (*ndo_select_queue)(struct net_device *dev, struct sk_buff *skb,
                        struct net_device *sb_dev,
                        select_queue_fallback_t fallback);
```

But it was changed to [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/source/include/linux/netdevice.h#L963) in 5.2:

```
u16 (*ndo_select_queue)(struct net_device *dev, struct sk_buff *skb,
                        struct net_device *sb_dev);
```

So the handler in `os_intfs.c` needs to change as well.

As a quick fix, simply dropping the `fallback` argument seems to get the build working for me:

```
diff --git a/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c b/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c
index b183a09..42f32a8 100644
--- a/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c  
+++ b/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c
@@ -1101,8 +1101,7 @@ unsigned int rtw_classify8021d(struct sk_buff *skb)

 #if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE>=KERNEL_VERSION(4,19,0))
 static u16 rtw_select_queue(struct net_device *dev, struct sk_buff *skb,
-               struct net_device *sb_dev,
-               select_queue_fallback_t fallback)
+               struct net_device *sb_dev)
 #else
 static u16 rtw_select_queue(struct net_device *dev, struct sk_buff *skb
 #if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3, 13, 0)
```

There's also a patch for this here: https://github.com/quickreflex/rtl8188eus/issues/28

Basically if you're uncomfortable with patches and source code, just go into your `os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c` at line 1103 and replace this:

```
static u16 rtw_select_queue(struct net_device *dev, struct sk_buff *skb,
                 struct net_device *sb_dev,
                 select_queue_fallback_t fallback)
```

with this:

```
static u16 rtw_select_queue(struct net_device *dev, struct sk_buff *skb,
                 struct net_device *sb_dev)
```

Comment: Sir so how I am suppose to fix the error..Actually I am a beginner so only have some basic knowledge.So I request you to kindly tell me step by step what to do to fix this problem.thanks.

Comment: You have to go to your `rtl8188eus/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c` file and do the change I mentioned above - remove the  `select_queue_fallback_t fallback` argument from the `rtw_select_queue` function ...